# How many Kafka consumers does a streaming query use for execution?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I was surprised to see that Spark consumes the data from Kafka with only one Kafka consumer, and this consumer runs within the driver container. I rather expected to see, that Spark creates as many consumers as the number of partitions in the topic, and runs these consumers in executor containers.

For example, I have a topic *events* with 5 partitions. I launch my Spark Structured Streaming app that consumes from this topic and writes to Parquet on HDFS. The app has 5 executors.
When examining the Kafka consumer group created by Spark, I see that just one consumer is in charge of all 5 partitions. This consumer is running on the machine with the driver program:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group spark-kafka-source-08e10acf-7234-425c-a78b-3552694f22ef--1589131535-driver-0

TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
events          2          -               0               -               consumer-1-8c3d806d-eb1e-4536-97d5-7c9d19582942 /192.168.100.147  consumer-1
events          1          -               0               -               consumer-1-8c3d806d-eb1e-4536-97d5-7c9d19582942 /192.168.100.147  consumer-1
events          0          -               0               -               consumer-1-8c3d806d-eb1e-4536-97d5-7c9d19582942 /192.168.100.147  consumer-1
events          4          -               0               -               consumer-1-8c3d806d-eb1e-4536-97d5-7c9d19582942 /192.168.100.147  consumer-1
events          3          -               0               -               consumer-1-8c3d806d-eb1e-4536-97d5-7c9d19582942 /192.168.100.147  consumer-1
```

After checking logs of all 5 executors, I found that only one of them was busy with writing the consumed data to Parquet location on HDFS. Other 4 were idle.

This is strange. My expectation was that 5 executors should consume data in parallel from 5 Kafka partitions and write in parallel on HDFS. Does this mean that the driver program consumes the data from Kafka and distributes it over executors? It looks like a bottleneck.

**UPDATE 1** I tried to add *repartition(5)* to the stream data frame:

```
spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokerhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "events")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()
    .repartition(5)
```

After that, I saw all 5 executors writing the data to HDFS (according to their logs). Nevertheless, I saw only one consumer (the driver program) on all 5 partitions of the Kafka topic.

**UPDATE 2** Spark version 2.4.0. Here is the command to submit the application:

```
spark-submit \
--name "Streaming Spark App" \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5 \
--class example.ConsumerMain \
"$jar_file"
```

Comment: Not sure, if you can have multiple consumers of the Kafka topics in spark streaming. However, spark's default partition count while KafkaUtils.createDirectStream is equal to the partition count of the Kafka topic. Hence in your case all 5 executors should be writing the data to HDFS, without repartitioning, reducing the reshuffing cost. So would recommend to use KafkaUtils.createDirectStream instead of spark.readStream.

Comment: @aavos _"while KafkaUtils.createDirectStream is equal to the partition count of the Kafka topic. "_ is about Spark Streaming, but the OP asks about Spark Structured Streaming. They are different streaming engines.

Comment: What's the Spark version? How do you `spark-submit` the application?

Comment: Updated the post with Spark version and the submit command

Comment: Is there any feedback on this? I´m facing the same issues using Spark 2.4.4

Comment: same issue here, if you resolve it, do till me

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs of Structured streaming, I can see it's mentioned as consumers being created on executors, [Consumer Caching](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#consumer-caching).